# dotnetnuke with ASP.NET 4.0, drawbacks?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Are there any potential drawbacks to using DotNetNuke 5.4 with ASP.NET 4.0 vs. ASP.NET 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real big risk at the moment would be with third-party components that might not have been tested/validated with the .NET 4.0 runtime.